# Gradle clean task fails for not resolving all dependencies

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

When I ran `./gradlew clean` for my Android project, the task failed for not resolving all dependencies. The complaints came from the gradle task **_debugCompile**.

I can verify *some of the local dependencies didn't exist* which failed the dependencies resolving process, but I'm still curious about **why the clean task would check for dependencies while not building the project.**

Shouldn't it just delete some directories as mentioned in the following link?
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:clean

Is there any gradle built-in task that could just clean the build folder without checking dependency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle already resolves dependencies during its configuration phase which precedes the execution phase, see [The Build Lifecycle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) (it downloads dependencies only once they are needed, though). However, dependencies being out of date does not make resolution fail. If resolution fails that dependency is likely not available online anymore. If you still have the dependency in your Gradle cache you might be able to work around this by specifying the [--offline](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sec:cache_command_line_options) switch:

```
$ ./gradlew --offline clean
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining:) So my understand is even for the task as simple as `clean`, gradle has to go through `initialization`, `configuration` and `execution` these three phases. In the `configuration` phase, gradle will resolve all the dependencies(check their availability?) and run the build scripts for the dependent projects. After all these are done, gradle will finally reach the `execution` phase and run the `clean` task. So there is no way to escape the process of checking dependencies before the `clean` task.  Is my understanding valid?

Comment: Yes. There is an incubating [--configure-on-demand](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand) [command line option](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_command_line.html) to only configure relevant projects (and not all of them) in the configuration phase, but that won't help here as `./gradlew clean` means to execute `clean` on all projects, so all of them are relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explaining:)